# Android based programming...loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

this may be a very simple question. I was working through a tutorial and I didn't bookmark the page so I can't go back to it.

Never the less I'm stumped by one small part of the java language which is potentially very simple but I'm new to it. What does the following mean, and can it be amended to count higher?

`for(int i=c.getCount()-1; i>=0; i--)`

I believe it's an integer counter, which assigns a the value of c.getCount to i, then subtracts one, makes i equal nothing and then adds 1 to i again... is this right? I need to increase this beyond one, so is that possible.

Comment: You may want to read some more about the for loop in java.

Comment: No, your interpretation is wrong. You should really just read a Java tutorial on loops. It's worth understanding the basics of Java *before* you start on Android, IMO. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html for a tutorial on the for loop.

Comment: What is your requirement  because question is complicated !!!

Comment: Here is another good link:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_for_loops.html

Comment: Thanks guys LGAP seems to have provided the help I needed. His insight to the fact that it's doing things in reverse has made me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a for loop of decrement!

Here the value of i would be initialized to `c.getCount()-1`

And then it checks if that is greater than or equal to zero and gets in to the loop.

After executing the loop contents, i count is decremented to 1. `i--`

And then again checks for the condition and runs the loop. The loop runs until the i value becomes lesser than 0.

Comment: If that is the case how do i get it to decrement from a number higher than one.

Comment: Ignore that retarded comment, I've figured it out. Thank you LGAP.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=c.getCount()-1; i>=0; i--)
```

This is a for loop which follows the sequence of steps like:

1. The statement i=c.getCount()-1 is assgining a value to i.
2. Then it will check the condition i is greater than or equal to 0.
3. If the condition is true the block of code in the for loop is executed.
4. Then i value will be decremented by 1.
5. Again the condition is checked and this process is repeated that is the loop     is iterated until the condition is false.
6. Once the condition fails the loop will be terminated.